# Directing all output to MessageConsole

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

Currently I am using `MessageConsole's`, `MessageConsoleStream` to write to console.

---

My question is, Is it possible to do some configuration such that everything I write to output stream is redirected to `MessageConsoleStream`.

---

Example, if I issue the following it should automatically write to the configured console.

1. `System.out.println("txt")`
2. `e.printStackTrace()`
3. In case Unchecked exception occurs (should automatically go to the console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect all `out` and `err` data, `System.out.println("txt")` and `e.printStackTrace()` are printed to the `out` stream while "Unchecked excepctions" are printed to the `err` stream.
In this example `System.out.println("txt")` would write `txt` to the `log.txt` file.

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("log.txt");
PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(out);
System.setOut(stream);
System.setErr(stream);
```

In your case you could do something like this:

```
MessageConsoleStream out = ...;
PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(out);
System.setOut(stream);
System.setErr(stream);
```